# How are regression residuals calculated for Panel data?

Tags: regression, residuals, stata

In cross-sectional data, the residuals are calculated along the individual observations.

But in panel data there is individual **and** time observation. So how are the residuals calculated?

Answer (score 1):

$e_{it}= \hat{Y}_{it}-Y_{it} $